# How does $(12)(34)(1) = (12)(1)\;$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to learn the proof that disjoint cycles are commutative and this is the first statement in the proof:

"If $i$ appears in the disjoint cycle $σ_1$ then it does not appear in the disjoint cycle $σ_2,$ so then $σ_1σ_2(i) = σ_1(i)$"

I just tried an example to see if this statement held where my $σ_1 = (12), \,σ_2 = (34)$ and $i = 1,$ which obviously appears in $σ_1$ as necessary.

However, surely $(12)(34)(1) = (12)(34)$? And not $(12)(1)$ as required?

Comment: @Hadi008 It seems that you are confusing the element $(1)$ and the operators $(12)$ and $(34)$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're getting confused by ambiguous notation. In particular, the $(1)$ appearing in the expression means "apply this permutation to $1$" rather than "multiply by the cycle $(1)$".

In particular, suppose we wrote application with square brackets instead. Then $(1\,2)[1]=2$, since the transposition switches $1$ and $2$, so applying it to $1$ gives $2$. Then $(1\,2)(3\,4)[1]=2$ as well, since $(3\,4)$ fixes $2$. Thus
$$(1\,2)[1]=(1\,2)(3\,4)[1]$$

Comment: +1, especially for square brackets - I hate this particular overuse of "(,)".

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "apply this permutation to 1" ? I've never seen anything like this.  Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: @Hadi008 Think of it this way: if $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a function, then $f(x)$ is $f$ applied to $x$.

Comment: @Hadi008 It might help if I knew more about how you viewed permutations now; generally, one thinks of permutations in $S_n$ as (bijective) functions $\{1,\ldots,n\}\rightarrow \{1,\ldots,n\}$. So, if $\sigma$ is a permutation, it sends $1$ to some value in the set, which is noted as $\sigma(1)$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I first encountered the word in Probability Theory so I view it in the combinatoric way; just a reordering of a set amount of numbers.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I think I understand what you're getting at now; thank you.

Comment: @Hadi008 If you think about orderings, then "application to $i$" would refer to taking the $i^{th}$ element in the order. For instance, if you have four elements $\{1,2,3,4\}$, then $(1\,2)$ could be taken to correspond to the order $2,\,1,\,3,\,4$ and $(1\,2)[1]$ would be the first element appearing - which is $2$.